# How to import another table's row count?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, django

[SOLVED]
I solved this issue just like this.

class article(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   likeCount = serializers.IntegerField(source='like_set.count', read_only=True)
   class Meta:
      model = article
      fields = ( ..., likeCount)

---

I'm using Django Rest framework. (DB = MySQL)

I want to import another table's row count.

[article table]
- articleNo(Primary key)
- userkey
- content
- likeCount

[like table]
- articleNo(FK to article)
- userkey

For example, articleNo == 1, counting number of row in a like table and storing article table's likeCount column.

All I want to know is about "like table", particularly suitable for a certian condition that counts values in table and list it to "article table"

Can it be implemented with Rest framework?

Thanks.

p.s. As I'm a non-native English speaker, it would be very appreciated if you use plain language to help my understanding.

**[Add more information]**

When I access to /article

```
{
    "articleNo": 1,
    "userkey": {
        "userkey": "12345",
        "username": "hide"
    },
    "content": "test",
    "likeCount": 0,
},
```

page return results like this. I want to counting all rows in like table realted articleNo is 1, and show it to likeCount field.

What I would like instead as output is something like:

```
{
    "articleNo": 1,
    "userkey": {
        "userkey": "12345",
        "username": "hide"
    },
    "content": "test",
    "likeCount": like table's row count when articleNo==1,
},
```

Comment: You seem to have some confusion of concerns here - are you looking for SQL, a way to process data, or something else? Please clarify your question and add an attempted solution if you can

Comment: @Avery I add more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to do this via a serializer. So, By Assuming, this can be done in the following way.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Article, ArticleLike

class ArticleSerialzer(serializers.Serializer.):
     def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        articleobj = Article.objects.get(articleNo=validated_data.get('articleNo', instance.articleNo))
        instance.likeCount = ArticleLike.objects.filter(articleNo=articleobj).count()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. But it seems little bit different what I want. I update more information, Please refer it.